# When I run JavaFx Application in Linux Fedora, my application crash..!

Tags: linux, javafx-2, fedora16, jnativehook

I have made JavaFx application which is running fine in Window , Mac OS but when i run in Linux Fedora the application make crash the whole system with the following log.

1) What is the reason of crash in Linux ?

2) What may the be the possible solution of this crash?

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00840e58, pid=2114, tid=2694839152  JRE version:
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13) 
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-x86 ) 
>   Problematic frame:  C  [libc.so.6+0x2fe58]  exit+0x38  Failed to write
>   core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try
>   "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again  If you would like to
>   submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp  The crash happened
>   outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.  See problematic
>   frame for where to report the bug.
>   ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
>
> Current thread (0xa0a8d800):  JavaThread "JNativeHook Native Hook"
>   [_thread_in_native, id=2306, stack(0xa01ff000,0xa0a00000)]
>
> ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------
>
> OS:Fedora release 14 (Laughlin)
>
> uname:Linux 2.6.35.6-45.fc14.i686 #1 SMP Mon Oct 18 23:56:17 UTC 2010
>   i686 libc:glibc 2.12.90 NPTL 2.12.90  rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k,
>   NPROC 1024, NOFILE 1024, AS infinity load average:20.56 6.52 4.06
>
> /proc/meminfo: MemTotal:        1013996 kB MemFree:          112652 kB
>   Buffers:            4224 kB Cached:           140000 kB
>
> Memory: 4k page, physical 1013996k(112652k free), swap
>   1535996k(665220k free)
>
> vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03) for linux-x86 JRE
>   (1.7.0_51-b13), built on Dec 18 2013 18:49:34 by "java_re" with gcc
>   4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)
>
> time: Mon Feb 10 16:29:44 2014 elapsed time: 15804 seconds

I am not entering the whole log because it is too long to post. please provide possible solution of Exception log

Answer (score 1):

Please file a bug at https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook with the entire crash log.  Chances are the issue has already been fixed in the 1.2 trunk.